# Fortran DLL in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, fortran

I am trying to compile some very old Fortran procedures in a DLL, so that to be able to use them with Delphi. Although the Fortran code is not very large (750-800 lines), its structure is very complicated with dozens of GOTO commands and the translation is not easy (I tried to make some useful code of it, but I failed).
Although I am new in Fortran, and not very experienced in calling DLLs, I gradually managed to overcome all the difficulties but for one, that is to be able to call the Fortran Subroutine with multiple dynamic arrays. Here’s a  simple example that I created:

```
      SUBROUTINE  MYSUB1( NoEquations, INTARR1 ) 
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::MYSUB1
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, REFERENCE, ALIAS:'MYSUB1' :: MYSUB1
C
C***************************************************************
C
         INTEGER    NoEquations, I
         INTEGER    INTARR1(*)
C
C***************************************************************
C
                 DO 100, I=1,NoEquations
                 INTARR1(I) = I 
  100    CONTINUE
      RETURN
C
      END

      SUBROUTINE  MYSUB2( NoEquations, INTARR1, INTARR2 ) 
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::MYSUB2
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, REFERENCE, ALIAS:'MYSUB2' :: MYSUB2
C
C***************************************************************
C
         INTEGER    NoEquations, I
         INTEGER    INTARR1(*)
         INTEGER    INTARR2(*)
C
C***************************************************************
C
                 DO 100, I=1,NoEquations
                 INTARR2(I) = INTARR1(I) 
  100    CONTINUE
      RETURN
C
      END
```

I compile the Fortran code with mingw-w64 with the following command:

```
gfortran -shared -mrtd -fno-underscoring -o simple.dll simple.f
```

And I declare the procedure from within Delphi with:

```
  procedure mysub1(var NoEquations: integer; var INTARR1        : array of integer); stdcall; external 'simple.dll';
  procedure mysub2(var NoEquations: integer; var INTARR1,INTARR2: array of integer); stdcall; external 'simple.dll';
```

The Delphi proram compiles correctly, but when I run it, mysub1 works correctly and updates INTARR1, but mysub2 gives me an Access Violation. Obviously, the second dynamic array confuses the compiler, but I do not know how to make it understand.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use an open array parameter. Use a pointer to array element type. Open array parameter has extra implicit parameter to specify the length.

Comment: Thanks! You mean one large array of integer and pointers to this array?

Comment: @Stelios Antoniou Problem is not in two array parameters, all declarations are wrong, the first procedure works properly by happy accident. `INTARR1,INTARR2: PInteger` might help. Also what about memory allocation?

Comment: @David Heffernan. Is there any example on how to make the call? Do I need to change both the Delphi and the Fortran code?

Comment: It seems just as much work both ways.  1000 lines of anything is not that hard to translate, doubly so something verbose like fortran.  My overwhelming preference here would be to rewrite.  "It's too hard" seems a weak reason to hold on to a sea anchor of legacy complexity.  I suspect with a bit of thought those 1000 lines could probably be rewritten into something half that size or smaller in Delphi while also becoming much cleaner and easier to read at the same time. You'll probably also end up understanding what the code does at the end of it - something we can infer you do not, at present.

Comment: Parameter type is PInteger and pass @arr[0]

Comment: Thank you both, I will try things myself

Comment: @David Heffernan, just to be 100% sure. You mean that I will pass a series of integer pointers and one large integer array at the end, right?

Comment: No. You replace `array of integer` with `PInteger` and pass `@arr[0]`

Comment: Many thanks @David Heffernan! I think I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know Delphi, but here is what you can do to create a DLL accessible from the C language. I hope you find it helpful. Here is your F77 code modified to make it interoperable via `iso_c_binding` module features of Fortran:

```
      SUBROUTINE MYSUB1(NoEquations,INTARR1) bind(C,name="MYSUB1")
         !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: MYSUB1
         use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: IK => c_int32_t
         integer(IK), intent(in), value :: NoEquations
         integer(IK), intent(out)       :: INTARR1(NoEquations)
         integer                        :: I
         DO 100, I=1,NoEquations
             INTARR1(I) = I
  100    CONTINUE
         RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE MYSUB1

C***************************************************************
C***************************************************************

      SUBROUTINE MYSUB2(NoEquations,INTARR1,INTARR2)
     +bind(C,name="MYSUB2")
         !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: MYSUB2
         use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: IK => c_int32_t
         integer(IK), intent(in), value :: NoEquations
         integer(IK), intent(in)        :: INTARR1(NoEquations)
         integer(IK), intent(out)       :: INTARR2(NoEquations)
         integer                        :: I
         DO 100, I=1,NoEquations
             INTARR2(I) = INTARR1(I)
  100    CONTINUE
         RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE MYSUB2
```

Note the many subtle but important changes that I have made to your code to make it interoperable with C:

1. The `bind(C,name="MYSUB1")` fixes the subroutine's name so you do not need the extra second compiler directives (which I have now removed from your code).
2. Also, note the `value` attribute which tells the compiler to pass by value as is done in C.
3. Also, note that I define the kinds of integers in the interfaces of the subroutine as `c_int32_t` to be compatible with the C processor's integer kinds.
4. Also, note that I have converted your **assumed-size** `INTARR1` and `INTARR2` arrays to explicit-shape arrays `INTARR1(NoEquations)`, `INTARR1(NoEquations)`.

Since you have the Intel `!DEC$` compiler directives in your code, I assume that you are using the Intel Fortran compiler on Windows. Note that I removed your second lines of directives in both Fortran subroutines.

Now, assuming that you store the above code in a file named `mysubs.F`, then compiling this file via the Intel Fortran compiler `ifort` on the Intel-Windows command prompt as in the following command,

```
ifort mysubs.F /dll /out:libsubs
```

will generate a DLL named `mysubs.dll` in the current folder and print the following message on the screen,

```
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.1.1.216 Build 20200306
Copyright (C) 1985-2020 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27027.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:mysubs.dll
-dll
-implib:mysubs.lib
mysubs.obj
   Creating library mysubs.lib and object mysubs.exp
```

To test this DLL, you can try the following C code stored in `main.c`,

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void MYSUB1(int32_t, int32_t []);
void MYSUB2(int32_t, int32_t [], int32_t []);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int32_t NoEquations = 5;
    int32_t INTARR1[NoEquations];
    int32_t INTARR2[NoEquations];
    int loop;

    // C rules for argument passing apply here

    MYSUB1(NoEquations,INTARR1);
    printf("\nINTARR1:\n"); for(loop = 0; loop < NoEquations; loop++) printf("%d ", INTARR1[loop]);

    MYSUB2(NoEquations,INTARR1,INTARR2);
    printf("\nINTARR2:\n"); for(loop = 0; loop < NoEquations; loop++) printf("%d ", INTARR2[loop]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this C code with the Intel C compiler,

```
icl main.c -c
```

prints the following on screen,

```
Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.1.1.216 Build 20200306
Copyright (C) 1985-2020 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
```

and generates the C main object file. Finally, link the C object file with the Fortran DLL library to generate the executable via the following command,

```
icl main.obj mysubs.lib -o main.exe
```

which prints the following on screen,

```
Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.1.1.216 Build 20200306
Copyright (C) 1985-2020 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27027.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:main.exe
main.obj
mysubs.lib
```

**Testing the DLL call**. Simply call the generated executable `main.exe`,

```
main.exe
```

which prints on screen,

```
INTARR1:
1 2 3 4 5
INTARR2:
1 2 3 4 5
```

Now, **to call this DLL from Delphi**, simply assume that you are calling the C functions with the prototypes specified in the C main code. That's all. No further dealing with Fortran from inside Delphi.

Final advice:

1. Fortran has powerful standard interoperability features, like the ones I have added to your F77 code, that can easily connect almost any Fortran code to any language (via C).
2. Stay away from FORTRAN77 which is almost a half-century old, even Fortran 90 is already more than 3 decades old. The latest Fortran standard was released in 2018, which together with Fortran 2008, makes Fortran an extremely powerful, high-level, fast, natively vectorized, concurrent, shared, and distributed parallel programming language for numerical computing.

Comment: Actually the issue in the question is in the Delphi code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan fair enough. But I do not get your downvote. This solution resolves many of the ad-hoc compiler patchworks done in the original code and in the compilation process by introducing the "proper standard approach" to Fortran interoperation, although it does not resolve the issue of connecting it to Delphi. But I also stated that explicitly in my answer.

Comment: The thing is, the crux is the error in the Delphi code of using a Delphi open array parameter. A complete answer has to address that.

Comment: @King. Thanks for the detailed response. A C compatible DLL is fully acceptrable by Delphi.